# Uncaught TypeError: fs.createWriteStream is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make a pdf file on client-side and afterwards it has to be send server-side through a REST call.

With the generation of the file, I have no problem. I use pdfMake to generate the file and that works fine.

Because I want to send the file to my backend, I have to store the file on the filesystem. To achieve this, I use node.js. The code below works fine. Only when I want to use a function of the object fs, I get the error 'Uncaught TypeError: fs.createWriteStream is not a function'. What am I doing wrong?

```
var docDefinition = localStorage.getItem('docDefinition');  
var PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake');
var printer = new PdfPrinter();

var pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(JSON.parse(docDefinition));

var fs = require('fs');
var stream = fs.createWriteStream('basics.pdf');
pdfDoc.pipe(stream);
pdfDoc.end();
```

Comment: Are you using `fs.createWriteStream` in the _browser_?

Comment: @robertklep I assume from the mix of fs and localStorage that such is indeed the case

Comment: I'm using it in the browser. The front-end is made with angularjs and jquery. It retrieves the data from a Spring Rest webservice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are confusing the server and the client. The browser has no *programmatic* access to the filesystem. Period. The filesystem api is triggered only via user interaction (like dragging and dropping a file on the webpage). You cannot write a file locally on the client.

Comment: It is my first time using this. I understand what you are saying.

Comment: Thats ok, hardly a day goes by that SO doesn't get 50 million questions that are all a variation of "how do I modify/access my PHP variable in JavaScript?"...so clearly you are not alone. Just remember that your server and client code can *only* communicate via HTTP by making an AJAX call. Send the JSON to your server, build the pdf there, and give the user a dynamically added link to download it, if that's what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for the advice