# "fs.createReadStream() is not a function" error(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, browser, html5-filesystem

> In my project of web development i need to use fs.createreadstream() function but >unfortunately filesystem is not availabe for browsers as of my knowledge. I tried >using level-filesystem,file-sytem,level-fs packages but everytime Im getting the >createreadstream() is not a function error .How to handle this problem???

Comment: You won't be able to access the file system directly using client-side javascript. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You tried do this in javascript? Or something else?

Comment: I need to use wordnet package which is available in npm.That package is using fs.createreadstream() function for reading file in its database.Is there any alternative solution for this ??

Comment: you can use "fs" with a nodeJS / server side application. You will not be able to run it in the browser unfortunately.

Comment: wordnet references very large files. The [nouns alone are 15 MB](https://github.com/dariuszdziuk/wordnet/blob/master/db/data.noun). You'd have to load all those files when you load the page. It seems incredibly impractical. You'd be better off writing a small server with an endpoint to do that logic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37569654/uncaught-typeerror-fs-createwritestream-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

I believe the browserify utility will allow you to use node.js style require statements like:

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

Comment: Are you able to share sample code or a repo for the project you are working on? Are you writing a node.js application to run on node or JavaScript to run on the browser?