# fs.createReadStream is undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, fs

So originally I was trying to use google cloud node client to do something.
Then the error

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): fs.createReadStream is not a function
```

keep showing up.

Here's the code snippet in "google-auth-library" that's been causing this

```
const fs = require("fs");
...
const filePath = path.resolve(this.keyFilename);
const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
await this.fromStreamAsync(stream, this.clientOptions);
```

I tried to print out fs and fs.createReadStream, and it shows fs is an object and createReadStream is of type undefined.

```
const fs = require("fs");

console.log( "createReadStream type...");
console.log( typeof fs.createReadStream );
```

The node version is v12.13.1, and I am running a react app initialized by create-react-app on Chrome.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: i think you have to provide path to file as the 1st argument to createReadStream.

Comment: Well I tried modifying google's source code and the 'filePath' is indeed what I passed in. Also I just tried giving path argument to createReadStream in my code and it shows the same error... @NileshJain

Comment: try to run just this part of the code separately to see if the code is having problem or something else is causing it, also try to print the filePath and see if its actually there. Also take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468205/fs-createreadstream-is-not-a-function-errorjavascript maybe you are having the same issue.

Comment: just search for the error on google you will get different posts and try to relate it to your situation.

Comment: You can't write to the file system directly from browser. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37570044/12232507.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import all the libraries or modules and define filePath correctly.

Try the following code:

```
 var fs      = require('fs'),
 path    = require('path'),
 url     = require('url');

 var fileUrl = 'http://beta.business.applane.com/rest/file/download'+ '?token=5437bdb1811dfb0f03ec49a3&filekey=541bc4c909e41ce549567c07';

 var filename,
 filename = path.basename(url.parse(fileUrl).path);

 console.log(filename);
 const t = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, filename));
 console.log(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

If, like me,  you encounter this problem while using

```js
import fs from  'fs';
```

use the following instead

```js
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

The issue you have is that `fs` doesn't have any `default` export which is what `import fs from 'fs'` will try to fetch.

What you want is to import `named` exports from `fs` which is what `import * as fs from 'fs'` will do.